# In MS Excel, what function should I use?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I have an original table:

```
Class 1  Class 2  Class 3   Class 4  Class 5  
Ram      Shyam    Madhu     Peter    Xavier  
Micheal  Cynthia  Helen     Rama     Hema  
Peters   Veronica Amy       Sydney   Backer
```

I want to know which class Amy is studying in.

What function should I use?

Comment: this is more of a [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) question, neh?

Comment: @erich This is a good question for here as it has to do with the functions of the software and not necessarily with programming. It might be off topic if it were specific to complicated VBA routines.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help with the function.

You are looking for [Range.Find Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx) .

[EDITED]

An example:

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:H12") 
    Set c = .Find("Ami") 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        c.Row = 1 'Row of "Class"
        MsgBox "Ami is in " & c.text
        Application.Goto c, True
    Else
       MsgBox  "Ami couldn't be found!"
    End If 
End With
```

Comment: Can you please give an example !

Answer (score 0):

A formula like this would work, (though there may be a simpler way) -

```
=INDEX(A1:E4,1,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Amy",A2:E4)),COLUMN(A1:E1),0)))
```

This also works, but in my opinion it's less effective than the one above -

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Amy",A2:E4)),COLUMN(A1:E1),0))))
```

These are array formulas, so you must **CSE** - type it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd> +<kbd>Entr</kbd>

If, say, you want to be able to change the string you're searching for, just change `"Amy"` to a cell reference where you type in your lookup value.

**Note - this will only give you the class of the *last time* the string appears**. So, if she takes more than one class it will return the last time she shows up in the array, starting at the top left and going down then over then down ....